# Crystal Reports exception in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

```
rptdoc.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true, "DO- " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HHmmss"));
```

Above line of code is throwing this exception:

> An exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Method not found: 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.PropertyBag CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.ISCRExportOptions.get_ExportOptionsEx()'

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and Crystal Reports 13

Comment: have you imported the (CrystalDecisions.Shared) and (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine) in you code??

Comment: also are you referencing your project to (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll) and (crystaldecisions.shared.dll)??

Comment: Yes I did all of your recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

Once I faced the same issue on my production server. 
until the day before everything was working good, but the next day, the error was showing up.

After long hours struggling with issue i remembered for some testing reasons, i had changed the "Application Pool Settings -> Enable 32-Bit Applications" to True, while my server is 64bit; i changed it back to false and everything got normal.

If your server is 32 make this option True, otherwise make it false.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to add this in your code:

VB.Net

```
 Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
 Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
```

C#

```
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
```

and Add a reference to your project for the required dll, or you can install crystal report viewer to your machine

Comment: Above namespaces are added, but still the same

Comment: what about the references

Answer (score 0):

if your windows is x64 make sure you make your application target x64 or any CPU not X86 
and the same if you use windows 32 bit make sure that you set  project to target x86