# Crystal report method not found

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, crystal-reports

I made a feedback project. I made it on ASP.NET MVC 5 it also has crystal reports. reports were working fine, but suddenly they stopped to work. I don't what happened with them. but since last week I tried hard to find solution but unfortunately could not get the right one who solved the solution. I downloaded different run times but all went vain. this is the bottom line of error.

> "Method not found: 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.PropertyBag CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.ISCRExportOptions.get_ExportOptionsEx()'"
>   this is the code:

public CrystalReportFeedback UserFeedbackDateWise(FeedbackReport be){

```
        if (Session["CurrentUser"] != null && Convert.ToInt32(Session["User_Id"]) != 0)
        {
            string reportPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), "UserFeedbackReport.rpt");
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                be.FromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(TempData["UserFromDate"]);
                be.ToDate = Convert.ToDateTime(TempData["UserToDate"]);
                be.User_Id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["User_Id"]);
            }
            return new CrystalReportFeedback(reportPath, be);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
            //new CrystalReportFeedback(reportPath, be);
        }
    }
```

Init of the report :

```
public CrystalReportFeedback(string reportPath, FeedbackReport be)//, object dataSet)
        {
            //int[] array;
            string strConnect = Convert.ToString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TSC"]);
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(strConnect);
            string _username = builder.UserID;
            string _pass = builder.Password;
            string _server = builder.DataSource;
            string _database = builder.InitialCatalog;
            ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
            //
            reportDocument.Load(reportPath);
            reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon(_username, _pass, _server, _database);
            if (be.Region_Id != 0)
            {
                reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@Region_Id", be.Region_Id);
            }
            if (be.User_Id != 0)
            {
                reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@User_Id", be.User_Id);
            }
            reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@FromDate", be.FromDate);
            reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@ToDate", be.ToDate);
            //reportDocument.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "C:\report.pdf");
            _contentBytes = StreamToBytes(reportDocument.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat));
        }
```

Export method :

```
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {

        var response = context.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Response;
        response.Clear();
        response.Buffer = false;
        response.ClearContent();
        response.ClearHeaders();
        response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
        response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(_contentBytes))
        {
            stream.WriteTo(response.OutputStream);
            stream.Flush();
        }
    }

    private static byte[] StreamToBytes(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Hope that I will get my solution at earliest.

this is modified code:

[HttpGet]

```
    public FileResult UserFeedbackDateWise(FeedbackReport be)
    {

        if (Session["CurrentUser"] != null && Convert.ToInt32(Session["User_Id"]) != 0)
        {
            string reportPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), "UserFeedbackReport.rpt");
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                be.FromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(TempData["UserFromDate"]);
                be.ToDate = Convert.ToDateTime(TempData["UserToDate"]);
                be.User_Id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["User_Id"]);
            }
            string strConnect = Convert.ToString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TSC"]);
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(strConnect);
            string _username = builder.UserID;
            string _pass = builder.Password;
            string _server = builder.DataSource;
            string _database = builder.InitialCatalog;
            ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
            //
            reportDocument.Load(reportPath);
            reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon(_username, _pass, _server, _database);
            if (be.Region_Id != 0)
            {
                reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@Region_Id", be.Region_Id);
            }
            if (be.User_Id != 0)
            {
                reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@User_Id", be.User_Id);
            }
            reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@FromDate", be.FromDate);
            reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@ToDate", be.ToDate);

            Stream stream = reportDocument.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);

            //Here i have my stream with my pdf report, i just create a new FileStreamResult and return it to my client like that : 
            FileStreamResult myfile = new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf");
            return myfile;
                //new CrystalReportFeedback(reportPath, be);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
            //new CrystalReportFeedback(reportPath, be);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the code  where you load your report, and when you export it, Thanks

Comment: Mr. @Furtiro please see the code

Comment: Last function exports the report

Comment: Hello, so you want to export your crystal report to a pdf, from your controller to your client ? If this is the point, i didn't see any crystal report initialization here, where do you create your report ?

Comment: string reportPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), "UserFeedbackReport.rpt");
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    be.FromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(TempData["UserFromDate"]);
                    be.ToDate = Convert.ToDateTime(TempData["UserToDate"]);
                    be.User_Id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["User_Id"]);
                }
                return new CrystalReportFeedback(reportPath, be);
            }

Comment: Mr. @Furtiro that code i wrote into my action

Comment: is this the you are talking about?

Comment: Yes, please post all the informations in your above post not in comment :)

Comment: please accept my apology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a coding issue, it's a runtime issue. The version of the crystal runtime or the bitness of your application.

One thing to try first is to upgrade both your development version and ensure you're running the same version in production. See https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/2148492 for more details

It says:

Compile your application either to 'X86 mode' or 'X64 mode'
Install the particular versions of runtimes on deployment machine.

i.e. If the application is compiled as 32 bit, then install the 32bit runtimes.

Comment: do you know how can i check the version of visual studio 2013? because this is my official laptop and everything was already installed in this laptop.
can you plz guide me

Comment: It's the version of crystal you need to upgrade. Check in the web.config file to determine what version your application is running. You want to be in the 13.x range, and watch the support pack version. You can download them from: https://blogs.sap.com/2016/12/06/sap-crystal-reports-developer-version-for-microsoft-visual-studio-updates-runtime-downloads/

Answer (score 0):

I'll try my best to help you exporting your report, but your post is not very clear. For your next post try to be very specific and provide as much information as you can.

I currently made a MVC project and export a crystalreport report from my controller to my client.

I think that your `ExecuteResult` method can work, but working with the httpcontext is useless, Crystalreport and .NET provide some useful methods to do the same.
 So i'll show you  how i create and export my report so you can copy / paste and modify your code.

Here is my controller method, called from a button :

```
[HttpGet]
    public FileResult InitReport()
    {
     //I create my report here
     FileImportReport rptH = new FileImportReport();

     // Some configuration on the report, datasource, databaselogon .. etc
     ...
     //

     //Then I export my report to a pdf stream like that :
     Stream stream = rptH.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);

     //Here i have my stream with my pdf report, i just create a new FileStreamResult and return it to my client like that : 
     FileStreamResult myfile = new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf");

     return myfile;

    }
```

My method is called from a button but it can work like you want, or the file can be saved in any known path.

You can test to reproduce my code, in your `CrystalReportFeedback` method use my code with your `reportDocument` object, you don't need to use your  `StreamToBytes` method.

Regards,

EDIT : Useful links with your error :

[Crystal Reports exception in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27165655/crystal-reports-exception-in-visual-studio-2013)

https://www.arcanadev.com/support/kb/K00000499.aspx

Comment: Mr.@Furtiro :'(

Comment: Which line cause this error ? I edited my answer with useful links, if working code don't work that could be a Crystalreport installation or runtime error ( or maybe config error )

Comment: Stream stream = rptH.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
this line displaying error

Comment: yes resolved. there was version problem. Thanx alot :)